# Is there an equivalent of Hero iOS for Android?

Tags: android, ios, animation, android-transitions

There is a great transition library for iOS called Hero (https://github.com/lkzhao/Hero)

Does anyone know of a similar library or interface to native options that do like solutions as Hero?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try these:

1. [Material-Animations](https://github.com/lgvalle/Material-Animations)
2. [Transitions-Everywhere](https://github.com/andkulikov/Transitions-Everywhere)

More libraries can be found on [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/).